# Stuck with Java Generic Classes

Tags: java, generics

I have an assignment and I'm stuck. The assignment is to write a generic class for this method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ValueStore<Object> myStore1 = new ValueStore<Object>(); 
    myStore1.set("Test"); 
    myStore1.get();

   ///
    ValueStore<Object> myStore2 = new ValueStore<Object>(); 
    myStore2.set(myStore1); 
    myStore1 = myStore2.get(); 
}
```

I've come this far.

```
public class ValueStore<T> {
    private T x;

    public void set(T x) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public T get () {
        return x;
    }
}
```

I am able to print out mystore.set "test", but not the myStore2.set. And I don't understand why my teacher passed in a reference variable as a argument. When I do that I get ValueStore@15db9742 in the console. Or maybe thats the point?

Can someone explain why it says `myStore2.set(myStore1); 
myStore1 = myStore2.get()`, what it should print and the logic behind it?

Thank you in advance. And sorry if my text is all messy. First time here.

Comment: Not too clear what your teacher wants but you can get around the `ValueStore@15db9742` problem by implementing a `String toString() {}` method in your `ValueStore` class.

Comment: Surely the implementation of `ValueStore#set` is supposed to include `this.x = x;`?

Answer (score 2):

I think currently you are just missing a line from your `set()` method, as in

```
public void set(T x) {
    System.out.println(x);
    this.x = x;
}
```

So that you would actually store the object.

Answer (score 0):

I have commented a bit more to explain. The main point is that you can give a type to your `ValueStore` (in this example, `String`). This makes the typesystem aware that when you call `get()` on the `valuestore`, it gets a `string` in return. This is actually the entire point of generics. If you simply put `object`, only you know that the get method will return a `String` so you would have to cast it (as in the second example).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Type your store with String, which is what generics is about.
    ValueStore<String> myStore1 = new ValueStore<String>(); 

    // Store a string in it.
    myStore1.set("Test");
    // Get the object, and the typesystem will tell you it's a string so you can print it.
    System.out.println(myStore1.get());

   ///
    ValueStore<Object> myStore2 = new ValueStore<Object>(); 
    // Store your store.
    myStore2.set(myStore1); 
    // The type system only knows this will return an Object class, as defined above.
    // So you cast it (because you know better).
    myStore1 = (ValueStore<String>) myStore2.get(); 
    System.out.println(myStore1.get());
}

public class ValueStore<T> {
    private T x;

    public void set(T x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public T get () {
        return x;
    }
}
```

This code prints the following:

```
test
test
```